# Making Perl's "specific declarations" as variable

Tags: perl, variables, hash

I was looking for some sort of solution if the following setup can be interpreted as formal declaration of the variables , if possible.
What i have is :

```
my $str_1 = "{cow}" ;

my $str_2 = "{cow}{black}{tasty_milk}";
```

what i want is :

(Based on above variable string is it possible to initialize a hash **directly**,
something like :)

```
my %hash=();

$hash."*some operator* on $str_i"  = 'Initialized' ;
```

This "some operator" should make $hash to  recognize as hash as it was declared earlier. i.e Input specific hash initialization.

PS: I don't want to write a function that will work on the string and  get all information to initialize the hash.

Comment: You might try JSON instead, it is easy to parse into a hash

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I suppose JSON may help. Let me see. Thanks Hakon.

Comment: See also [Creating hash of hash dynamically in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36033603/2173773) and [Read config hash-like data into perl hash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24396250/2173773)

Comment: I'm afraid your question is clear as mud. What is the expected output?

Comment: Jcaron I want to read a string which will have the format same as like what hash expects to have , for ex: "{xyz}{mno}{abc}" , but this strings are not know beforehand as they are some variable's output. I want to directly initialize a hash based in this string.like : $hash{xyz}{mno}{abc}="done";(constraint is to write as small code as possible)

Comment: Where are these strings coming from?

Comment: In JASON we can parse the string to DS. Its good enough.

Comment: This string are output of some function which append various encoded property of some structure under test into this string.  If this property is initialized in the hash or not i want to move ahead in the code.

Comment: Do you control that function?

Comment: No.Its output are well structured .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you had the following input instead:

```
my @path = qw( cow black tasty_milk );
```

Then you can use the following:

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

DiveVal(\%hash, map \$_, @path) = 'value';
```

So, with [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Diver), we get:

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

$str =~ /^(?:\{\w+\})+\z/
   or die("Unrecognized format");

my @path = $str =~ /(\w+)/g;
DiveVal(\%hash, map \$_, @path) = 'value';
```

Without a module:

```
sub dive_val :lvalue { my $p = \shift;  $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;  $$p }

$str =~ /^(?:\{\w+\})+\z/
   or die("Unrecognized format");

my @path = $str =~ /(\w+)/g;
dive_val(\%hash, @path) = 'value';
```

Comment: @reinierpost, It validates the input, parses the input, then sets the hash element. How is that not obvious?

Comment: It is obvious that it tries to do something like that, but with the question not being stated clearly and your code being extremely terse without any comments, I have trouble understanding what is going on and above all why, and I'm someone who has been working with Perl code for 20 years.

Comment: Which one is it? Is what it does obvious, or do you have a hard time understanding what it does?

Comment: It isn't obvious what it does, and it isn't obvious that it is what jordan vj wants.

Comment: @reinierpost, You are gravely mistaken. It's very obvious that a check that results in `die("Unrecognized format")` checks if the input is in a recognized format. I can't believe I have to tell you that if you've ever programmed before (in any language).

Comment: @reinierpost, You are gravely mistaken. The purpose of `my @a = $str =~ /(...)/g;` -- to extract text from a string -- is very obvious since it's a construct from Perl 101 used daily. I can't believe I have to tell you that if you've ever used Perl. [You should know that!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5353007/589924)

Comment: @reinierpost, You are gravely mistaken. Even though it's used as an lvalue, it's painfully obvious that `DiveVal(...)` is a subroutine call. Seriously, man? "20 years of experience"???

Comment: You repeatedly brought into question the clarity of the OP's question, but the only thing that's unclear is the extent of what's they consider a valid input. To address that, my answer documents the inputs for which it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with anonymous hash

```
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings; 
use strict;

my $str_2 = "{cow}{black}{tasty_milk}";
my %hash;
my $ref =\%hash;
my $val;
my $lp = () = $str_2=~m/\}/g; #count the number of }
my $i = 1;
while($str_2=~m/\{(\w+)\}/g)
{
    $val = $1;

    last if ($lp == $i); 

    $ref->{$val} = {}; #make the anonymous hash        

    $ref = $ref->{$val};   #add the data into anonymous hash

    $i++;

}
$ref->{$val} = "value"; #add the last value

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: By the way, `my $ref =\%hash;
my $val;
my $lp = () = $str_2=~m/\}/g;
my $i = 1;
while($str_2=~m/\{(\w+)\}/g)
{
    $val = $1;

    last if ($lp == $i); 

    $ref->{$val} = {};

    $ref = $ref->{$val};

    $i++;

}
$ref->{$val} = "value";` simplifies to `my $p = \\%hash;
    $p = \( $$p->{$1} ) while $str_2 =~ /\{(\w+)\}/g;
    $$p = "value";
`

Comment: @ikegami It is very amazing. I have tried to know your trick but I can't please shall you explain this.? :)

Comment: The trick is to add a layer of indirection. More about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31554981/589924) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30766598/589924)